# Why does this visual ghosting appear when I wrap a WebBrowser with a Border?

Tags: wpf, xaml, browser, border

Here's the XAML:

```
<Border Margin="5 0 50 10" BorderBrush="#1d1d1d" BorderThickness="5" CornerRadius="5" Width="940">
    <WebBrowser x:Name="GuideBrowserControl" Cursor="Arrow" Width="930" Height="550"></WebBrowser>
<Border>
```

Here's what the ghosting looks like:

[image]

When I scroll too fast the borders top and bottom lines double or triple. I have to scroll away, and slowly scroll to it for it to appear correctly.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour is called 'bleeding'.  There is a blog article by Ryan Vogrinec entitled "*Clipping legacy content hosted inside a WPF scrolling region*" that will give a recipe for its cure...

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ryanvog/archive/2009/01/20/clipping-legacy-content-hosted-inside-a-wpf-scrolling-region.aspx